# http.HandleFunc invokes root handler 3 times per request

Tags: http, go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

type pageFunc func() (string, interface{})

func thread() (string, interface{}) {
    return "thread", nil
}

func main() {

    t := template.New("main")
    t.ParseGlob("templates/*.xhtml")

    respond := func(f pageFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
        fmt.Println("respond 1")

        return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            fmt.Println("respond 2")
            name, data := f()
            t.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
        }
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/", respond(thread))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":7842", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

Starting the program above and sending a single request to `http://localhost:7842/` causes the console to output:

```
respond 1
respond 2
respond 2
respond 2
```

It only appears to invoke the handler a single time if I comment out:

```
name, data := f()
t.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
```

In that case I just get:

```
respond 1
respond 2
```

This is completely beyond my comprehension. How would calling t.ExecuteTemplate cause the function it's invoked from to run more than once? Even more bizarre (to me, at least) is that if I change the path slightly, like so,

```
http.HandleFunc("/a", respond(thread))
```

... it once again only fires the handler function once, even with the templating function uncommented. What is happening?

The template in question, if it interests anyone:

```
{{ define "thread" }}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>test thread page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/board.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/general.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>hello, world.</h1>
    </body>
</html>
{{ end }}
```

Comment: There's something in your template that's causing your browser to make multiple lookups to "/"? Can you post a minimal template that exhibits the behavior?

Comment: I should have made a note of it but I left the template out because there's not much interesting going on in it. It's there now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the  "single request" is made by a browser then it may actually be more than one request. Eg. some browsers may ask for a site favicon. If you want a guaranteed single request then I would recommend to write a simple tool for that purpose.

Comment: Never mind. I just tested it with curl, and you're right. Only one response. Thanks. What a dumb question.